# Need excel formula for total cost from matching of other text column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want the Total Mark column by matching with two column that has text (Name & ID). Would appreciate you guys can help me with the excel formula.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7aB6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Few array (CSE) & SUMPRODUCT formula can achieve the goal.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get unique list in ascending order the array forrmula in cell M27:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($I$27:$I$35,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($I$27:$I$35,"<"&$I$27:$I$35)-SUM(COUNTIF($I$27:$I$35,"="&M$26:M26)),0)),"")}
  ```
- Enter this array formula in cell L27:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2, 1/((COUNTIF($L$26:L26, $H$27:$H$35)<>"")*($I$27:$I$35=$M27)), $H$27:$H$35),"")}
  ```

*Finish array formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.*

- Formula in cell N27:

  ```
   =IF(SUMPRODUCT(($H$27:$H$35=$L27)*($I$27:$I$35=$M27)*($J$27:$J$35))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(($H$27:$H$35=$L27)*($I$27:$I$35=$M27)*($J$27:$J$35)))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help U @Md. Arifur Rahman ,, keep asking ☺